# Max subarray sum in CLRS (3rd edition) resulting in error

Tags: python, clrs

This is a continuation to my early [complaints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311126/mergesort-resulting-in-error-in-clrs-3rd-edition) about [CLRS(3rd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) if you're looking to learn about algorithms, this is by far the worst book that you can ever use. All the pseudocode examples up to chapter 4 that I've seen so far have mistakes ranging from off by one, wrong/missing base cases for recursive functions, poor design choices that require complete redesign ex: the use of sentinel values in merge sort which is addressed in my other question I mentioned earlier. This book is overhyped and is plain garbage.

In the example shown below, the objective is to find a contiguous subarray with the largest sum.

> ex:
> [13, -3, -25, 20, -3, -16, -23, 18, 20, -7, 12, -5, -22, 15, -4, 7]

sequence: `18, 20, -7, 12`: 43

> ex:
> [4, 5]

sequence: `4, 5`: 9

[image: max-crossing-subarray]

```
def max_crossing_subarray(a, low, mid, high):
    left_sum = -float('inf')
    total = 0
    max_left = None
    for i in range(mid, low - 1, -1):
        total += a[i]
        if total > left_sum:
            left_sum = total
            max_left = i
    right_sum = -float('inf')
    total = 0
    max_right = None
    for i in range(mid + 1, high):
        total += a[i]
        if total > right_sum:
            right_sum = total
            max_right = i
    return max_left, max_right, left_sum + right_sum
```

[image: max-subarray]

```
def max_subarray(a, low, high):
    if high - low == 1:  # `high == low` is wrong and results in recursion error
        return low, high, a[low]
    else:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        left_low, left_high, left_sum = max_subarray(a, low, mid)
        right_low, right_high, right_sum = max_subarray(a, mid, high)
        cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum = max_crossing_subarray(a, low, mid, high)
        if left_sum >= right_sum and left_sum >= cross_sum:
            return left_low, left_high, left_sum
        if right_sum >= left_sum and right_sum >= cross_sum:
            return right_low, right_high, right_sum
        else:
            return cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum
```

It works for some examples: list size > 2, otherwise, fails:

```
s1 = [13, -3, -25, 20, -3, -16, -23, 18, 20, -7, 12, -5, -22, 15, -4, 7]
s2 = [2]
s3 = [4, 5]
for s in s1, s2, s3:
    print(s)
    print(max_subarray(s, 0, len(s)))
    print(70 * '=')
```

**Result:**

```
[13, -3, -25, 20, -3, -16, -23, 18, 20, -7, 12, -5, -22, 15, -4, 7]
(7, 10, 43)  # correct sum, inclusive indices are correct
======================================================================
[2]
(0, 1, 2)  # correct sum, exclusive indices are correct
======================================================================
[4, 5]
(1, 2, 5)  # all wrong
======================================================================
```

**Question: code producing wrong/inconsistent results, what's wrong? why? how to fix?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't think @FrankYellin knows either. Could you clarify what you need help with by editing your question?

Comment: Code producing wrong/inconsistent results? what's wrong? why? how to fix?

Comment: You do have an error in your first translation.  `for j = mid+1 to high` includes "high".  Your `for i in range(mid+1,high):` does not.

Comment: Related to that, your call should be `print(max_subarray(s, 0, len(s)-1))`.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood what you're pointing to, I think this is because all the book examples are 1-indexed which you have to keep into consideration when translating to 0-indexed languages, `high` when being the size of the list, will result in index error.

Comment: Thirdly, in your second translation, in line 5, you need to have `(a, mid+1, high)`, and you left off the "+1".  If you make those changes and go back to back to `if high == low:`, then it all works.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct, it works, and was included in @shriakhilc 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code given by the book treats `low` and `high` as inclusive indices. So firstly your call to the method should be

```py
print(max_subarray(s, 0, len(s)-1))
```

There is no recursion issue with `max_subarray()` and the if condition should be left as `if low == high:`.

The call for the right half of the subarray should have `mid + 1`

```py
right_low, right_high, right_sum = max_subarray(a, mid+1, high)
```

And in `max_crossing_subarray()`, the loop condition should be `for i in range(mid + 1, high + 1):`.

With all those changes made, the output becomes:

```
[13, -3, -25, 20, -3, -16, -23, 18, 20, -7, 12, -5, -22, 15, -4, 7]
(7, 10, 43)
======================================================================
[2]
(0, 0, 2)
======================================================================
[4, 5]
(0, 1, 9)
======================================================================
```